# What DLL resources uses Windows XP to show its icons?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, icons, dll, resources

I want to change the Windows XP icons.

I know that Windows 7 depends of `imageres.dll` for show icons, like folders, files, Computer icon, ...

But, what is the DLL file that Windows XP depends for show its icons?

Answer (score 0):

Till Windows XP, most icons are stored in the `shell32.dll`. Some Explorer related Icons are indeed stored in the `Explorer.exe`. Since Windwos Vista, the icons are stored in `imageres.dll`.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but on XP those standard system icons may actually be an embedded resource in explorer.exe. Possibly some other executable, but I would look in there first.

Comment: This seems like a comment considering you are not sure what file is responsible

Comment: It was a _suggestion_, based on something I seem to recall. At least I've given him a better idea of where to look than you just did.